# Jaime Lannister - "I have dreamed this dream before"

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, literary-analysis

While reading [A Storm of Swords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Storm_of_Swords) I reached the chapter where Jaime is being treated by Qyburn and I want to know more about Jaime's dream:

> Jaime closed his eyes and let the wine and Qyburn do their work. “Tell me of the battle.” As keeper of Harrenhal’s ravens, Qyburn would have been the first to hear the news.
>   “Lord Stannis was caught between your father and the fire. It’s said the Imp set the river itself aflame.”
>   Jaime saw green flames reaching up into the sky higher than the tallest towers, as burning men screamed in the streets. I have dreamed this dream before. It was almost funny, but there was no one to share the joke.

I believe Jaime knew about the caches of Wildfire under King's Landing which the Mad King was wanting to light during the sacking of the city, so I'd be satisfied to believe that he's just saying "I thought about this during the sacking of the city", but before that I was wondering if there was any further evidence for or against the other possibilities:

- That Jaime really had a prophetic/green dream about it
- That Jaime was actually tormented by this since he killed the King

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Up to the end of *A Dance With Dragons*, Jaime never has had a prophetic dream/vision concerning Wildfire. So this almost certainly refers to the hidden caches of Wildfire spread throughout King's Landing by the King Aerys II.

This is reinforced by the end of the above quote:

> It was almost funny, but there was no one to share the joke.

The hidden Wildfire, and Aerys' intention to use them, was largely unknown and a secret Jaime kept to himself. As far as I recall, the only person Jaime shared this story with is

> Brienne

later on in *A Storm of Swords*. Thus he has no one to share the joke of King's Landing/Lord Tywin/etc. being saved by the caches of Wildfire originally created for the sole purpose of killing them all.